# Renaming WCF generic class with DataContract Name attribute

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

My WCF interface looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
   [OperationContract]
    Foo<String>[] Test();
}
```

The `Foo<T>` class looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "FooOf{0}")]
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I publish the WCF service and add service reference to my client code, then I use this method like this:

```
var client = new ServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(@"http://myServer:port/Service.svc"));
FooOfString[] result = client.Test();
```

However, I cannot access the properties of the generated classes, for example, I cannot do this:

```
var value = result[0].Value; // cannot access property, does not compile
```

I am able to do the EXACT same thing by removing the `[DataContract(Name = "FooOf{0}")]` part of my `Foo<T>` class and I can access the properties, the problem is the name of the generated class which changes to `FooOfStringCHtiIp13` and that looks ugly, I'm trying to rename it to something a bit more readable. This operation, however, now works:

```
FooOfStringCHtiIp13[] result = client.Test();
var value = result[0].Value; // can access, compiles
```

It feels like something does not get serialized and I am not using this correctly. Any idea how to achieve this correctly?

Comment: `FooOf{0}` formats the generated class name to `FooOfT`, where `T` is in my case `Bar`

Comment: Try adding a DataMember attribute to the Value property?

Comment: I just tried that as you wrote your comment.. that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem, the issue was in my `Value` property of `Foo<T>` class, I had to add `DataMemberAttribute` to my property:

```
[DataContract(Name = "FooOf{0}")]
public class Foo<T>
{
    [DataMemberAttribute(Name = "Value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```